# Terraform: Credential error when importing aws resources - error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: ExpiredToken

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I have some aws resources that I want to import into my terraform state.

I have set the aws credentials in `~/.aws/credentials` file:

```
[my-profile]
aws_access_key_id=<ACCESS_KEY_ID>
aws_secret_access_key=<SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>
aws_session_token=<SESSION_TOKEN>
```

`terraform init` ran successfully, but when I try to import the resources with:

```
terraform import -var-file=config/us-west-2/default.tfvars -var-file=variables.tfvars -var-file=../globals.tfvars -var profile=my-profile -var region=us-west-2 -var tfstate_bucket=<MY_TF_BUCKET> -no-color <RESOURCE_NAME> <RESOURCE_ID>
```

I am getting following error even when my credentials have not expired:

```
Error: error using credentials to get account ID: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: ExpiredToken: The security token included in the request is expired
    status code: 403, request id: 1684ef71-ecea-4fed-bcf5-a32eca688ab4
```

**Please Note** that I have ran similar imports in another non-production aws account, but I get this error when I try to run it against production account. I do have power-user access to the Production account though.

**Terraform version:**

```
Terraform v0.12.29
+ provider.aws v3.14.1
+ provider.null v2.1.2
+ provider.random v2.3.1
+ provider.template v2.1.2
```

---

**EDIT:** Printing environment variables on my mac

```
$ env
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
TMPDIR=/var/folders/jz/w997kd9x4sb983kdyj8wjlkc0000gp/T/
GRADLE_HOME=/Users/john/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.k5lBL3QJ9R/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=421.2
TERM_SESSION_ID=D2EB66E5-2DD7-456A-8E16-A0E00CE15112
SDKMAN_PLATFORM=Darwin
USER=john
SDKMAN_CANDIDATES_API=https://api.sdkman.io/2
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.GG8D8SvuqA/Listeners
PATH=/Users/john/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PWD=/Users/john/MyProjects/tf/foobar
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SDKMAN_VERSION=5.7.4+362
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
HOME=/Users/john
SHLVL=1
LOGNAME=john
SDKMAN_DIR=/Users/john/.sdkman
SDKMAN_CANDIDATES_DIR=/Users/john/.sdkman/candidates
_=/usr/bin/env
```

---

**EDIT 2:**
When I cleaned up all the old profiles and credentials so that `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config` only has entry for `my-profile` and nothing else.

Also all related environment variables:

```
for var in AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY AWS_SESSION_TOKEN AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN ; do eval unset $var ; done
```

So now I am getting:

```
Error: No valid credential sources found for AWS Provider.
    Please see https://terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html for more information on
    providing credentials for the AWS Provider
```

Comment: Isn't it the case that your AWS one-time credentials are expiring because the Terraform commands run for too long?
Can you try adjusting the expiration period?

Comment: They are valid for 1 hour and my command terminates with this error in less than a minute.

Comment: You might have some other credentials (in environment variables?) which get in the way.

Comment: Thanks, I printed env variables on my Mac (added in the question above), doesn't look like there is any conflicting creds. Is there anything else I should check for?

Comment: You might also inspect the `.tfvars` files your command lists.

Comment: Sure, will check that. Yes. that's the only other thing which differs for the aws account where it worked vs doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki Pls see my second edit and a new error. Seems like `terraform import` is unable to read that profile from the creds.

Comment: So now you don't have any credentials set. You need to use one of the methods to provide AWS credentials. I think most of the time people do that by setting the environment variables: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#environment-variables

Comment: I have it in the `credentials` file as well as I have set the same through the env variables as you suggested. But that gives `Error: Error loading state: AccessDenied: Access Denied status code: 403, request id: <ID>, host id:<HOST_ID>`

Comment: We use a shell script for running the `terraform plan` and `terraform apply`. It turned out that there are things which get setup with this script. And when I use that even for `terraform import` the credentials worked fine. Thanks for your help @GrzegorzOledzki.

Comment: So one can say your script for `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` is leaking the credentials. At least leaving the "workspace" in a different state. You might want to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, the most likely answer is that you have some old credentials "stored" somewhere:

- either still in your current terminal session's environment variables
- or in one of the `.tfvars` file your command mentions

I suggest to clean them up. Get new credentials. And try again.

Comment: It's not about the old credentials. It's using the correct credentials. But may be some environment variable is set in the script such as `TF_DATA_DIR` or some `.tfvar` or the S3 bucket containing remove `.tfstate`.

Comment: +1 for you pointers & help. So essentially our environment is setup to run terraform commands through this script so that it can set things up as intended. And I was trying to run the `terraform import` directly that caused it to not work.