# Terraform getting error when configuring S3 Backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

trying to store my state file in an s3 bucket , but getting this error when trying 'Terraform init' :

- made sure my aws credentials doesnt have " / # $ .. "

```
error configuring S3 Backend: error validating provider credentials: 
error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: 
InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

main.tf :

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = var.region
  access_key = var.acc_key
  secret_key = var.sec_key
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "mybucket-terra-prac"
    key            = "terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "eu-central-1"
  }
}
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = var.ami
  instance_type = "t2.large"
  associate_public_ip_address=true
  key_name = var.public_key
  tags = {
    Name = var.ec2_name
  }
}
```

variables i have in variables.tf file ( with type and default ) :

```
variable "acc_key" {}
variable "sec_key" {}
variable "public_key" {}
variable "ami" {}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try execute `aws sts get-caller-identity` command and see you are using correct credentials.

Comment: if you can confirm the same error of `aws sts get-caller-identity`
you can update

`export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxx`
`export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxx`
`export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=xxxxx`
[link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html)
It seems terraform tf is using those env vars

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was able to resolve the issue by deleting the `.terraform/` folder then running the `terraform init` again.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure but I think you can't use variables when specifying `region` in `aws provider` section. I think you need to hardcode that to your region. Also again not entirely sure but using variables in the `secret` and `access` key should be hardcoded instead of pointing it to a variable ( these parameters are meant to be used when specifying values inside terraform file directly ).

And the `terraform` section should be placed in the beginning of the file before `aws provider` section.

Comment: hey , thank you for your answer but tried all and didnt work .. ( terraform block befor provider , hardcode region  + acc + secret key )

Comment: Okay that is really strange then. If you are able to you can remove the existing state file and initiate the terraform again ( once again, DO IT ONLY IF YOU ARE NOT IN PRODUCTION or you can afford to delete the tfstate file ). But I think it's more likely that something is wrong with your access token or you don't have the right IAM permissions for the bucket. You can check what IAM policies you need [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html) but I am sure you've already seen this page.

Comment: You can also try to generate a new access key and see if it works that way.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870211/terraform-credential-error-when-importing-aws-resources-error-calling-stsget) question?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error:

```
Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
      status code: 403, request id: f07a9a38-ef21-44ee-a122-71800b865fea

  with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
  on main.tf line 1, in provider "aws":
   1: provider "aws" {
```

It turned out the region I was working in was [not enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpIyJ.png). FYI, it takes a few minutes to enable a region.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, first I needed to configure MFA on my AWS CLI (company policy), then I edited the
`~/.aws/credentials (vim ~/.aws/credentials)` to add a correct profile.

In my case it was showing `[default]`. After editing I was still getting error on vs code. I tried on local terminal and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was. I have an existing aws token defined in `~/.aws/config`

Try to check it out especially if you are using multiple profiles.

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor client searches for credentials by using the default credentials in system environment variables: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.

So UnSet them.

Then execute `aws sts get-caller-identity` command and see if you are using correct credentials.

Answer (score 0):

go with "aws configure"  on your console and add new/old credentials it will do,cause mine worked fine after that

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your AWS provider missing "token" field.
Try adding this field to you AWS provider section.
Your AWS provider block should look like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = var.region
  access_key = var.acc_key
  secret_key = var.sec_key
  token      = var.token
}
```

Also don't forget to add to your file variables.tf this line:

variable "token" {}

Answer (score -2):

```
terraform init
-backend-config="access_key=${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY }}"
-backend-config="secret_key=${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}"
```

[Copied from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Terraform/comments/su13lo/comment/hxai3zn/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)